# Error in implementing lazy assign in C++

Tags: c++, lazy-evaluation, crtp

I have some weird issues implementing the lazy assign and add as indicated in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicInsideEigenExample.html.

The code is

```
template<typename Derived> class Base;
template<typename Derived, typename OtherDerived> class SumOp;

template<typename Derived, typename OtherDerived>
class SumOp: public Base<SumOp<Derived, OtherDerived>>{
public:
    Derived & lhs;
    OtherDerived & rhs;

    SumOp(Derived & lhs_, OtherDerived & rhs_):lhs(lhs_), rhs(rhs_){}
    double  packet(size_t index, Base<OtherDerived>& src){
        return lhs.packet(index)+ rhs.packet(index);
    }
};
template<typename Derived, typename OtherDerived>
struct Assign{
    static Derived& run(Derived & dst, OtherDerived & src){
        size_t length = dst.size();
        for (size_t index =0; index < length; index++){
            dst.copyPacket(index, src);
        }
        return dst;
    }
};


template<typename Derived>
class Base{
public:
    Base(){}
    Derived& derived(){
        return *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    }

    const Derived& derived() const{
        return *static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
    }

    template<typename OtherDerived>
            SumOp<Derived,OtherDerived> operator+(Base<OtherDerived> & other){
                return SumOp<Derived, OtherDerived>(this->derived(), other.derived());
    }

    template<typename OtherDerived>
       Derived & operator=(Base<OtherDerived>& other){
        return Assign<Derived, OtherDerived>::run(derived(), other.derived());
    }
    template<typename OtherDerived>
            void copyPacket(size_t index, Base<OtherDerived> & other){
        derived().writePacket(index, other.derived().packet(index));
    }
};


class Vector: public Base<Vector> {
public:
    double * data;
    size_t nRow;

    Vector(size_t nRow_):nRow(nRow_){
        data = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*nRow);
    }
    ~Vector(){
         free(data);
    }
    template<typename OtherDerived>
            Vector& operator=( Base<OtherDerived>& other){
        return Base<Vector>::operator=(other);
    }
    size_t size(){
        return nRow;
    }
    void writePacket(size_t index, double src){
        data[index] = src;
    }
    double packet(size_t index){
        return data[index];
    }
};
```

In short, the problem lies in when I call `operator=` in Vector class, where the compiler complains that I have passed a left value `Base<SumOp<Vector, Vector>>` to the operator instead of `SumOp<Vector, Vector>&`. The latter of which is created when calling `operator+`, which returns `SumOp<Vector, Vector>`.

The compiler error is

```
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SumOp<Vector, Vector>’ to ‘Base<SumOp<Vector, Vector> >&’
```

I am not sure why the implementation in Eigen is OK and how to fix this issue.

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

The problem occurs when I call the following functions

```
void test_vector(){
    Vector a(10), b(10), c(10);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        a.data[i]=1.0;
        b.data[i]=1.0;
    }
    //This is very it goes wrong
    c = a+b;


    for (int i =0 ; i<10;i++){
       std::cout << c.data[i]  << std::endl;
    }

};
```

With g++-6 the error reads

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Base<SumOp<Vector, Vector> >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘Base<SumOp<Vector, Vector> >’
     c = a+b;
         ~^~
In file included from /home/ran/Desktop/experiment/PointerMatrix/vector.cpp:6:0:
/home/ran/Desktop/experiment/PointerMatrix/vector.h:76:21: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Vector& Vector::operator=(Base<OtherDerived>&) [with OtherDerived = SumOp<Vector, Vector>]’
             Vector& operator=( Base<OtherDerived>& other){
```

Comment: I can't seem to [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20b82584350dab32) your problem, both GCC 6.1 and Clang 3.8

Comment: Let me try with gcc6

Comment: Already did~ Thank you very much for reminding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because the arguments to your `operator` functions aren't const references.  `operator+` returns a temporary `SumOp` object, which cannot be passed as a non-const reference.  (Some compilers may support this as an extension.)

Changing the parameters to be `const &` types should fix this problem.

Comment: Exactly! I thought I can bypass the problem of const but I am wrong.......

Comment: It would be worth mentioning about forwarding references for this case